# SQLite сортировка текста в котором содержаться английские и русские слова Android

Tags: android, sqlite, сортировка

Нужно получить список слов с одного столбца, в котором будут английские и русские слова в алфавитном порядке. Так же если это невозможно или трудно выполнимая задача.
Как отсортировать уже полученный список таким же образом ?
Нужно что бы сначала были русские слова в алфавитном порядке, после английские слова в алфавитном порядке.

Comment: а в чём именно проблема? Какой ваш код некорректно работает при добавлении в список русских слов?

Comment: Сейчас я использую вот такую выборку из базы.  `Cursor cursor = database.query("имя таблицы", null, null, null, null, null, "имя столбца");`  Я получаю список в котором сначала английские слова, после русские. А мне надо что бы изначально были русские слова, после английские

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String rule = "&А,а<Б,б<В,в<Г,г<Д,д<Е,е<Ё,ё<Ж,ж<З,з<И,и<Й,й<К,к<Л,л<М,м<Н,н" +
            "<О,о<П,п<Р,р<С,с<Т,т<У,у<Ф,ф<Х,х<Ц,ц<Ч,ч<Ш,ш<Щ,щ<Ъ,ъЫ,Ы,Ь,ь<Э,э<Ю,ю<Я,я" +
            "<A,a<B,b<C,c<D,d<E,e<F,f<G,g<H,h<I,i<J,j<K,k<L,l<M,m<N,n<O,o<P,p<Q,q" +
            "<R,r<S,s<T,t<U,u<V,v<W,w<X,x<Y,y<Z,z<0<1<2<3<4<5<6<7<8<9" +
            "<'!'<'@'<'#'<'$'<'%'<'^'<'&'<'*'<'('<')'<'_'<'+'<'±'<'§'<'<'<'>'<'/'<'?'<'.'<','<'\"'<';'<':'<'\\'<'|'<'`'<'~'<'['<']'<'{'<'}'"
```

Это правило для колатора `java.text.RuleBasedCollator`
Из базы не получится запросом отсортировать как вы хотите, сортируйте колатором

Comment: Хотел уже написать вариант с компаратором он мне выбивает сначала английские потом русские. Решил сделать определение первой буквы и в случае если английская то возвращать -1. Я правильно думаю?

Comment: так колатором можно пользоваться внутри компаратора. Определение буквы - будет работать криво. Коллатор более чистое и не такое сложное решение, а самое главное - правильное.